# $\sum_j \sin(x_jt) \coth(\alpha x_j)$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have given the following formula and need to find the intervals in which $f(t)$ for $ t \in [0, \infty]$ is negative, $f(t) <0$. Note that $\alpha, x_j >0 $

$f(t)= \sum_{j=1}^N \sin(x_jt) \coth(\alpha x_j)$

I understand how it works for the 1-dim case $N=1$ but I think I am missing something here, as I don't know how to solve this. 
Any help or hint would be appreciated. I thought about Fourier Series but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I need to find the intervals in which $f(t)$ is negative for $t \in [0, \infty]$

Comment: Does the $\coth$ factor depend on $t$?

Comment: @ Maxim No it doesn't but the $x_j$ depend on the summation

Comment: Then it seems to be just $\sum a_j \sin x_j t$, with some positive $a_j$. That seems too broad to be able to make any conclusions. We don't even know whether the sum is periodic or not.  Btw, don't put spaces between @ and username in @username :).